# problem in showing pagination in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

hey guys i made a pagination for my site

here  :

http://nukelearn.com/

problem is showing  pagination correctly in IE

style for pagination  is here :

http://nukelearn.com/includes/mods/JQ-Forums/css/style.css

plz give me a hint to correct this problem in ( hated browser : IE )

Answer (score 0):

Actually in IE8 is just the same as in Chrome .. i don't see anything wrong, but have you noticed your javascript error?

Webpage error details

Message: 'getLoad' is undefined
Line: 105
Char: 311
Code: 0
URI: http://nukelearn.com/

Are you missing external js file ? or something else ?

Comment: I think Yvette is referring to the pagination halfway down the page.